# reusable helper for test assertion in Django

Tags: python, django

I am writing unit tests for a Django 1.4 app. In my tests.py, I would like to have a helper function that I can use in my test classes. The helper is defined as such:

```
def error_outcome(self, response):
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
    data = json.loads(response._get_content())
    self.assertEquals(data, {'error': 1})
```

Below is an example test class that uses the helper:

```
class SomeTest(TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):    
        request = RequestFactory().post('/someurl')
        response = view_method(request)
        error_outcome(self, response)
```

This works, however it is not good because the helper should not be using self as it is a function, not a method. Any idea on how to make this work without self? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a base test case class with the `error_outcome()` method defined:

```
class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    def error_outcome(self, response):
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
        data = json.loads(response._get_content())
        self.assertEquals(data, {'error': 1})

class SomeTest(BaseTestCase):
    def test_foo(self):    
        request = RequestFactory().post('/someurl')
        response = view_method(request)
        self.error_outcome(response)
```